# Chronic not parsing time correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Chronic in a rails app as shown below. I have a form that has separate text fields (jquery dropdowns) for the date and the time. In my model I have virtual attributes that are supposed to write the combined data-time to the DB using Chronic to parse. Chronic is parsing the dates correctly, but no matter what time I put in the text field, it outputs 12:00:00 as the time in the datetime field. I've tested the types of inputs in IRB and it seems to work fine, am I missing something here?

Model:

```
class VisitBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :start_date_text, :time_text
  attr_writer :start_date_text, :time_text
  before_save :save_start_date_text

  def time_text
  end

  def start_date_text
    @start_date_text || visit_date_start.try(:strftime, "%m-%d-%Y")
  end

  def save_start_date_text
    self.visit_date_start = Chronic.parse("#{start_date_text} #{time_text}").in_time_zone if @start_date_text.present?
  end
```

Console Log:

```
Started POST "/visit_blocks" for ************** at 2013-04-21 19:56:20 +0000                                                                                                                                                             
Processing by VisitBlocksController#create as HTML                                                                                                                                                                                     
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ns4YyAL9a44RU3T/wOw+DPcigVbBd6eQ5wz1exq3g1M=", "visit_block"=>{"start_date_text"=>"04/22/2013", "time_text"=>"05:15 AM"}, "hou
r"=>"05", "minute"=>"15", "meridian"=>"AM", "button"=>""}                                                                                                                                                                              
  Client Load (4.8ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."last_name" IS NULL LIMIT 1                                                                                                                                   
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  SQL (3.2ms)  INSERT INTO "visit_blocks" ("visit_date_start") VALUES (?)  [["created_at", Sun, 21 Apr 2013 19:56:20 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sun, 21 Apr 2013 19:56:20 UTC +00:00], ["visit_date_start", Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:00:00 UTC +00:00]]                                                                                                                                                               
   (6.7ms)  commit transaction
```

Comment: What type is `visit_date_start`? The parsing works fine AFAICT, using the params shown in your log: `Chronic.parse("#{start_date_text} #{time_text}").in_time_zone => Mon, 22 Apr 2013 09:15:00 UTC +00:00` Are you sure the params are being pulled out correctly?

Comment: From schema.rb: t.datetime "visit_date_start". I'm not sure how to test if the params are getting pulled out correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I hadn't defined "time_text" correctly in my model. I found out by printing the relevant date/time in my console.

Print to log file (came up nil)

```
p time_text
```

Corrected time_text definition:

```
@time_text || visit_date_start.try(:strftime, "%I:%M %P")
```